# How to close Automatic Debugger in chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, javascript-debugger

[When debugging in chrome, the scripts are always paused in the debugger even if there are no break points set, and if the the pause is un-paused, it again pauses itself.[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyLgd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your chrome dev tool and go to your settings
under preference select disable javaScript

[image]